# moveRowAt Reorder TableView with Realm

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I have Realm model:

```
class ShoppingListItem: Object {
    @objc dynamic var department: String = ""
    var item = List<ShoppingItem>()
}

class ShoppingItem: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var checked: Bool = false
    @objc dynamic var sortingIndex = 0
}
```

I try to add functinality to reorder rows for tableView. This is my code:

```
var shoppingList: Results<ShoppingListItem>!

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return shoppingList?.count ?? 0
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return shoppingList[section].item.count
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShoppingCell", for: indexPath)
    
    let oneItem = shoppingList[indexPath.section].item[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = oneItem.name
    
    if oneItem.checked {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName: "app.fill")
  } else {
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(systemName: "app")
  }
    
    return cell
}
```

What I should add to function moveRowAt to have the possibility to reorder rows? This is code example. How I should modify it to make it works with Realm?

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        
            let moved = shoppingList[sourceIndexPath.section].item[sourceIndexPath.row]


            shoppingList[sourceIndexPath.section].item.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
            shoppingList[destinationIndexPath.section].item.insert(moved, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the cool things about Realm List objects is they maintain their order.

In this case you would not need the sortingIndex property since those items are stored in a List.

```
class ShoppingListItem: Object {
    @objc dynamic var department: String = ""
    var item = List<ShoppingItem>() <- order is maintained
}
```

When you re-order a row in your tableView, reflect that change in the list by by inserting it at a new position and removing it from the old (which is done first depends on which direct the object is moved). You can either do it manually using .insert and .remove

```
itemList.remove(at: 5) //remove the shoppingItem object at index 5
itemList.insert(shoppingItem, at: 1) //insert the object at index 1
```

or use the super easy .move to move the object from one index to another.

```
itemList.move(from: 5, to: 1)
```